# how to increase width of the images in only in one page

Tags: html, css, magento

Our page design is not displaying properly [here](http://snlogistics.com/art-graphics/sony-xperia-z1.html)

But other pages are working fine like [here](http://snlogistics.com/cases-covers/art-graphics/lg-g3.html)

```
@media only screen and (min-width: 1224px)
.main-container a {
    color: #ff7704;
    font-size: 14px;
    font-weight: normal;
    text-decoration: none;
}
```

Comment: code is mismatch between them.Is this wordpress?

Comment: @iyyappan its magento site

Comment: now check links, "sort by " is having problem

Comment: I noticed that the links in your question are dead. Do you still have the original code? The answers below are meaningless without it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove below css code or Comment it.

```
.col3-layout .col-wrapper {
/* float: left; */
/* width: 79.16667%; */
```

}

```
.col3-layout .col-wrapper .col-main {
/* float: right; */
/* width: 73.68421%; */
```

}

```
.col-main {
/* float: left; */
/* width: 75%; */
```

}

and you forgot to add below div after .col-main div

```
    <div class="block block-layered-nav glace_navigationlayer-filters-left block-layered-nav glace_navigationlayer-filters-left--no-filters" id="desktop-layer-navigation" style="position: relative; top: auto; left: auto; width: auto; padding: 0px; height: auto; box-shadow: none; z-index: 100; background: none;">
    <!--<div class="block-title">
        <strong><span></span></strong>
    </div>-->
    <div class="block-content toggle-content">
        <!---->                            <p class="block-subtitle block-subtitle--filter">Filter</p>
            <dl id="narrow-by-list">
                                                                <div class="navigation">
                    <dt class="odd">Device</dt>
                    <dd class="odd" style="display: none;">
                        <ul>
                            <li><ol>
<li><a class="glace_navigationlayer-attr" href="#">LG G3 (55)</a></li></ol></li>
                        </ul>
                    </dd>
                </div>
                                                                <div class="navigation">
                    <dt class="even">Design</dt>
                    <dd class="even" style="display: none;">
                        <ul>
                            <li><ol>
<li><a class="glace_navigationlayer-attr" href="sitename">Art &amp; Graphics (55)</a></li></ol></li>
                        </ul>
                    </dd>
                </div>
                                                                <div class="navigation">
                    <dt class="last odd">Category</dt>
                    <dd class="last odd" style="display: none;">
                        <ul>
                            <li>
<ol>
            <li class="glace_navigationlayer-cat glace_navigationlayer-cat-level-1">
                            <a href="sitename">Art and Graphics                                    </a>
        </li>
            <li class="glace_navigationlayer-cat glace_navigationlayer-cat-level-2">
                            LG G3                                    
        </li>
    </ol></li>
                        </ul>
                    </dd>
                </div>
                                            </dl>
            <script type="text/javascript">decorateDataList('narrow-by-list')</script>
            </div>
</div>
```

Comment: images are fine now. please check links now, "sort by " is having problem

Comment: sorry , i am not geting `.col-main div`

Comment: wait i m giving you screenshot link

Comment: in this div you have to add above div that i posted in answer

Comment: thanks a lot for your continous support, i am still working on this issue, stil not found solution, i will accept your answer for sureonce i get solution.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/114949/discussion-between-sagar-kodte-and-nsdlfefinedieicbe).

Comment: yes.. no problem..if you need something tell me..:)

Comment: is it possible to solve this issue only with css instead of using html

Comment: it will.. but can you tell me there is only one option sort by. You need only one here?

Comment: you can see this [link1](http://stylebaby.com/cases-covers/animals/xperia-t3.html)

[link2](http://stylebaby.com/cases-covers/animals/xperia-t2.html) i want to display exactly similar to link2, i need all 4 - design, category, device, sort by all options

Comment: No you can't do it without adding above div because now there is no html code of this 4 options. so you have to add it.

Comment: still one more text " stylebaby" left , please remove that one also.  you will get once you search thorough CTRL + F>

Comment: still one more text " stylebaby" left , please remove that one also. you will get once you search thorough CTRL + F>

Answer (score 1):

**Please try this**

.Add the below div before the `<div class="category-products">`.

```
<div class="" style="height: 20px;"></div>
<div class="category-products">
```